# How do I debug the cause of a network outage on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

I have a website running on a Windows Server virtual hosting service (Godaddy).  I run a website that gets about 200 visitors a day and a teamspeak server and that's it.  I am new to Windows Server management and I'm still reading on how to manage servers properly and securely.  I have what seems to be intermittent network outages lasting from 30 seconds to up to 10 minutes.  I have yet to find anything in the logs to explain it.

I am trying to understand what my process should be for figuring out the cause of the network outage.  I want to rule out the provider as the cause or have proof they are the cause.

Answer (score 3):

A good/simplest way to check provider is to use an external monitoring tool, e.g. Pingdom. It will spot internet connection outage. There is also the one I'm involved with - [Anturis](http://anturis.com) (in beta, so free for now). It is good as you'll be able also to install agent on the server and check other metric through it - to check problems at OS and software level.

Comment: Good suggestion if you're not yet an 'expert' on the server admin side, alot of IT companies use this type of tech to manage remote servers.

Answer (score 1):

You could install Wireshark on the server and start capturing the interface - that would give you some better information.

Are you sure it's not resources as opposed to the network traffic?

Comment: I suppose it could be some task that is going out of control.  Would keeping task manager running for a couple days be the best way to figure something like that out, or would there be a better tool for that?

Comment: You can use perfmon to monitor this, because you wont be able to tell until it goes down - it may be worth looking at the suggestion from meriadoc as you may spot it before it goes down. Couldn't be you've made an enemy and they're ddos'ing you?

Comment: The logs don't seem to point to a DDOS attack, the server should be able to handle the current volume of connections.  I'll probably try something like cloudshare as last option.  I see the other types of usual hacking attempts going on (SQL Injection attempts and attempts to remote in), but nothing successful and nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Last suggestion is to check any scripts, like if you've anything PHP with curl and check timeouts, or possibly they're getting stuck for another reason.

Comment: Good thought, I'll go check out php.ini now.